# How do I create a Categorial with my own levels in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a CSV, and I'd like to make one of the columns a Categorical, with my own ordering.  How do I do that?  The three labels are 'read', 'write' and 'mixed'.  Here are some things that don't work:

```
Categorical(my_csv.rw, ['read', 'write', 'mixed'])
    ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'mixed'

Categorical(my_csv.rw, Index(['read', 'write', 'mixed']))
    ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'mixed'

Categorical(['read', 'mixed', 'write'], Index(['read', 'write', 'mixed']))
    ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'mixed'

Categorical.from_array(['read', 'mixed', 'write']) # Levels in wrong order
```

So, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the levels are ordered by the labels:

```
In [38]: a.levels
Out[38]: Index([mixed, read, write], dtype=object)

In [39]: a.labels
Out[39]: array([1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: This is the default.  Is it possible to change the default?

Comment: Unfortunately not right now. It should be easy enough to add methods like sort_labels, sort_levels, and/or sort(indexer) though. Would you be interested in making a pull-request on github? We'd very much welcome any community contributions

Answer (score 0):

Categorical expects an array of integers and an array of levels:

```
In [14]: Categorical([0, 1, 2], Index(['read', 'write', 'mixed']))
Out[14]: 
Categorical: 
array([read, write, mixed], dtype=object)
Levels (3): Index([read, write, mixed], dtype=object)
```

I do not believe it does much error checking (since typically they're created by some other function) but this could be changed.